# Add a css class on “form_widget” when errors happen

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like add a CSS class on a form_widget() when errors (specific to field) happen.

For now, I have this code :

```
{{ form_widget(form.firstName, {'attr': {'class': 'text-input'}}) }}
```

It generates this HTML code :

```
<input type="text" id="userbundle_member_firstName" name="userbundle_member[firstName]" required="required" class="text-input" />
```

It's good but I want when error(s) happen (exemple the value is too short), a css class will added. So, I want to have something like that :

```
<input type="text" id="userbundle_member_firstName" name="userbundle_member[firstName]" required="required" class="text-input error-input" />
```

I tried searching solution on the doc (especially [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)), but I have not been able to do what I want.

Thank you for your help :D !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell Twig about your custom form's templates:

**app/config/config.yml**

```
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources:
            - 'YourBundle::form.html.twig'
```

And override them (check *vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form*):

**src/YourBundle/Resources/views/form.html.twig**

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% if form.vars.errors|length > 0 %}
{% set class = attr.class is defined ? attr.class ~ ' error' : 'error' %}
{% set attr = attr|merge({'class': class}) %}
{% endif %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

**UPDATE**

The method described above will change the rendering of all the form fragments, if you only need to change some form then you can do it locally, just read the docs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming)

Comment: This overrides any form template already in place. We just need to inject a class, not redefine the rendering.

Comment: @afilina, you can change the rendering of a form fragmente in the place avoiding a global change, check https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming

Comment: @afilina, did you just downvote me? my answer here is correct and is not a bad practice, if you need another thing just read the docs or ask it here.

Comment: @afilina, now there is an small note about this, please consider upvoting.

Comment: @afilina, is sad to see no feedback from you after taking the time to clarify this (taking in account that the answer was valid before and you shouldn't be downvoting just because it doesn't fit your needs).